# Runtime type resolution on a non-default constructible class without polymorphysm

Tags: c++, code-reuse

I have a bit of a puzzle. I have a template class `graph` with a template parameter - a class `vertex`, that can be either symmetric or asymmetric, compressed or raw, and I only know which at runtime.

So if I wanted to get the graph of appropriate type from disk, run Bellman Ford on it and then free the memory, I would need to repeat the template instantiation in all four branches of conditionals, like so:

```
#include "graph.h"
int main(){
// parse cmd-line args, to get `compressed` `symmetric`
// TODO get rid of conditionals. 
if (compressed) {
  if (symmetric) {
    graph<compressedSymmetricVertex> G =
      readCompressedGraph<compressedSymmetricVertex>(iFile, symmetric,mmap); 
    bellman_ford(G,P);      
  } else {
    graph<compressedAsymmetricVertex> G =
      readCompressedGraph<compressedAsymmetricVertex>(iFile,symmetric,mmap); 
    bellman_ford(G,P);
    if(G.transposed) G.transpose();
    G.del();
  }
} else {
  if (symmetric) {
    graph<symmetricVertex> G =
      readGraph<symmetricVertex>(iFile,compressed,symmetric,binary,mmap); 
    bellman_ford(G,P);
    G.del();
  } else {
    graph<asymmetricVertex> G =
      readGraph<asymmetricVertex>(iFile,compressed,symmetric,binary,mmap); 
    bellman_ford(G,P);
    if(G.transposed) G.transpose();
    G.del();
  }
}
return 0;
}
```

**QUESTION**: How can I extract everything except the call to the `readGraph` functions outside the conditionals with the following restrictions.

1. I cannot modify the graph template. Otherwise I would have simply moved the Vertex type into a union.
2. I cannot use `std::variant` because `graph<T>` cannot be default constructible.
3. Call overhead is an issue. If there are subtyping polymoprhism based solutions that don't involve making `compressedAsymmetricVertex` a subtype of `vertex`, I'm all ears.

**Edit**: Here is a sample header `graph.h`:

```
#pragma once
template <typename T>
struct graph{ T Data; graph(int a): Data(a) {} };

template <typename T>
graph<T> readGraph<T>(char*, bool, bool, bool) {}

template <typename T> 
graph<T> readCompressedGraph<T> (char*, bool, bool) {}

class compressedAsymmetricVertex {};

class compressedSymmetricVertex {};

class symmetricVertex{};

class asymmetricVertex {};
```

Comment: How come you only know _type_ properties _at runtime_? If at runtime, what's wrong with dynamic polymorphism?

Comment: why is it related to polymorphysm? You may need overloaded constructor or simply normalize the input before pass it to constructor.

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Comment: @rustyx Can you elaborate what your problem with the question is? I find it reasonably specific, throwing the "How to Ask" link in people's faces without further explanation is pretty rude in my eyes. Similar for MCVE when the code is a sketch for a design question, not some debugging problem.

Comment: So what exactly is it that you want to do? You have different behaviour according to parameters that are only known at runtime, so there's no way for the compiler to help here

Comment: @appleapple, @lxop, the reason for relating this to polymorphism is because it fits neatly into polymorphism, but not subtyping (e.g. if I declared a `class vertex`, and inherited all of the subtypes.

Comment: _"Virtual functions and hence inheritance runtime polymorphism are out of question."_ May I ask why? Are you afraid of call overhead or is there a more specific issue? Also, can you not modify `vertex` or `graph` at all?

Comment: What are `compressed`, `symmetric`? Are those type traits, some runtime flags, or something else? Why do you talk about a template parameter, is there some type information?

Comment: Your question reminds me of parsing since you mention reading from disk. http://boost-spirit.com/ is a heavy weight parser that can do such lifting for you. Essentially you end up running into a visitor pattern where you resolve your dynamic type.

Comment: @MaxLanghof, "May I ask why?" Mostly the overhead, to some extent readability. I'll make another edit, to make it more obvious. "Can you not modify `vertex` or `graph`?" No. I need to use an upstream repository as a submodule and so far the developer of `ligra`, has ignored every pull request from my fork.

Comment: You can't move the use of the various `G`s to a wider scope than where each is defined. They are all unrelated from each other, so they can't go in the same scope. Other than writing four lots of `doGraph(VertexType = {}, ...)` you can't tidy this up

Comment: @rustyx, Runtime flags. I use `getopt` to parse commandline options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you did not spell out all the types, and did not explain what is going on with the `binary` parameter, I can only give an approximate solution. Refine it according to your exact needs. This should be in line with:

```
class GraphWorker
{
public:
   GraphWorker(bool compressed, bool symmetric)
   : m_compressed(compressed),  m_symmetric(symmetric)
   {}
   virtual void work(const PType & P, const char * iFile, bool binary, bool mmap ) const = 0;
protected:
   const bool m_compressed;
   const bool m_symmetric;
};

template <class GraphType>
class ConcreteGraphWorker : public GraphWorker
{
public:
  ConcreteGraphWorker(bool compressed, bool symmetric)
  : GraphWorker(compressed, symmetric)
  {}
  void work(const PType & P, const char * iFile, bool binary, bool mmap) const override 
  {
      graph<GraphType> G =
      readGraph<GraphType>(iFile, m_compressed, m_symmetric,
                           binary, mmap); 
      bellman_ford(G,P);
      G.del();
  }
};

static const std::unique_ptr<GraphWorker> workers[2][2] = {
    {
      std::make_unique<ConcreteGraphWorker<asymmetricVertex>>(false, false),
      std::make_unique<ConcreteGraphWorker<symmetricVertex>>(false, true),
    },
    {
      std::make_unique<ConcreteGraphWorker<compressedAsymmetricVertex>>(true, false),
      std::make_unique<ConcreteGraphWorker<compressedSymmetricVertex>>(true, true),
    }

};

int main()
{
    workers[compressed][symmetric]->work(P, iFile, binary, mmap);
}
```

**Some comments**: It is better to avoid `bool` altogether, and use specific enumeration types. This means that instead of my two-dimensional array, you should use something like:

```
std::map<std::pair<Compression, Symmetry>, std::unique_ptr<GraphWorker>> workers;
```

But since there could be other unknown dependencies, I have decided to stick with the confusing `bool` variables. Also, having `workers` as a static variable has its drawbacks, and since I don't know your other requirements I did not know what to do with it. Another issue is the protected Boolean variables in the base class. Usually, I'd go with accessors instead.

I'm not sure if all this jumping-through-hoops, just to avoid a couple of conditionals, is worth it. This is much longer and trickier than the original code, and unless there are more than 4 options, or the code in `work()` is much longer, I'd recommend to stick with the conditionals.

**edit:** I have just realized that using lambda functions is arguably clearer (it is up to debate). Here it is:

```
int main()
{
  using workerType = std::function<void(PType & P, const char *, bool, bool)>;
  auto makeWorker = [](bool compressed, bool symmetric, auto *nullGrpah) 
  {
      auto worker = [=](PType & P, const char *iFile, bool binary, bool mmap) 
      {
          // decltype(*nullGraph) is a reference, std::decay_t fixes that.
          using GraphType = std::decay_t<decltype(*nullGrpah)>;
          auto G = readGraph<GraphType>(iFile, compressed, symmetric,
                           binary, mmap); 
          bellman_ford(G,P);
          G.del();

      };
      return workerType(worker);
  };
  workerType workers[2][2] {
      {
        makeWorker(false, false, (asymmetricVertex*)nullptr),
        makeWorker(false, true, (symmetricVertex*)nullptr)
      },
      {
        makeWorker(true, false, (compressedAsymmetricVertex*)nullptr),
        makeWorker(true, true, (compressedSymmetricVertex*)nullptr)
      }
  };

  workers[compressed][symmetric](P, iFile, binary, mmap);
}
```

Comment: I really like the idea behind this answer, It's a bit complex for what I need, but I have learned at least two new things from it.

Comment: @AlexPetrosyan I just realized that it is possible to use lambda, and it is much simpler. I'm adding it to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The simple baseline is that whenever you want to cross from "type only known at runtime" to "type must be known at compile-time" (i.e. templates), you will need a series of such conditionals. If you cannot modify `graph` at all, then you will be stuck with needing four different `G` variables (and branches) whenever you want to handle a `G` object in a *non-templated* function, as all the `graph` template variants are unrelated types and cannot be treated uniformly (`std::variant` aside).

One solution would be to do this transition exactly once, right after reading in `compressed` and `symmetric`, and stay fully templated from there:

```
template<class VertexT>
graph<VertexT> readTypedGraph()
{
    if constexpr (isCompressed<VertexT>::value)
        return readCompressedGraph<VertexT>(/*...*/);
    else
        return readGraph<VertexT>(/*...*/);
}

template<class VertexT>
void main_T()
{
    // From now on you are fully compile-time type-informed.
    graph<VertexT> G = readTypedGraph<VertexT>();
    bellman_ford(G);
    transposeGraphIfTransposed(G);
    G.del();
}

// non-template main
int main()
{
    // Read parameters.
    bool compressed = true;
    bool symmetric = false;

    // Switch to fully-templated code.
    if (compressed)
        if (symmetric)
            main_T<compressedSymmetricVertex>();
        else
            main_T<compressedAsymmetricVertex>();
    // else
      // etc.
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/g/vNFHoA)

You will probably have to write a lot of meta-functions (such as `isCompressed`) but can otherwise code as normal (albeit your IDE won't help you as much). You're not locked down in any way.

Comment: "(albeit your IDE won't help you as much)". Not a problem, emacs doens't do much anyway.

Comment: If I may, what's the significance of `constexpr` in this code?

Comment: @AlexPetrosyan Presumably `readCompressedGraph<symmetricVertex>` would not compile. With `if constexpr`, that branch is (more or less) skipped if the condition is false and won't produce a compiler error.